# Cómo puedo agregar animaciones a mi sitio web usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, animación

estoy creando un sitio web y me gustaría agregar algunas animaciones a mi diseño para que sea mas llamativa visualmente. Tengo entendido que se pueden agregar animaciones utilizando JavaScript, pero no se por donde empezar.

¿Hay alguna biblioteca o método que pueda utilizar para hacer esto de manera más fácil? También me gustaría saber cómo puedo personalizar las animaciones y hacer que se ajusten a mi diseño.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda o consejo que puedan ofrecer. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Nicolás DS88. Puedes intentar hacer animaciones con setInterval, o con requestAnimationFrame. Para más info, te dejo el siguiente enlace: https://es.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css-js/html-js-dom-animation/pt/animating-styles-with-css-animations

Comment: No es necesario el uso de Javascript, también puedes lograrlo con [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations), aunque es experimental, tiene soporte en casi todos los navegadores actuales.

Comment: jquery, prueba con esto https://api.jquery.com/animate/, aun que lo mejor es css en combinación con js cambiando las clases, es lo que mas utilizo